# Where is "Camera Profile" in Adobe Camera Raw 11.2?

Tags: photoshop, raw, adobe-camera-raw

In **Adobe Camera Raw**, it used to be possible to specify a **Camera Profile** here:

[image]

However, in the version 11 of **Camera Raw** in **Photoshop CC**, this essential feature is nowhere to be found:

[image]

"Version 5, 4, 3, 2, 1" are not what I'm looking for - I need to upload a Camera Profile I made.

Dragging the .dcp file onto the Photoshop icon is even more staggering:

[image]

***Am I missing something here, or has Camera Profile manual selection moved or been removed from Photoshop?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camera profiles are moved on the first tab (Basic) in ACR:
[image]

To install new profiles you should copy the .DCP files in
MAC: `[UserName]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Camera Raw/Settings`

WINDOWS: `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw\Settings`

Comment: This does not answer my question. How do I select the .dcp camera profile I have created with Adobe DNG Profile Editor? I clicked on "Profile" then "Browse" but didn't find a way to import. I clicked on the little lines to the right of "Basic" on your screenshot - but neither "Custom" nor "Load settings" worked either. Look at the first screenshot in my question - where Canon EOS is circled, this is what I need to display.

Comment: @MicroMachine, please check my edited answer

Comment: Should it go in "Settings" folder, or inside the "Adobe" folder within it? (Which contains "Presets" and "Profiles" both of which have several ..xmp files inside of them. When placed in the "Settings" folder, nothing changes in the "Profile" menu of your screenshot. Could you create a .dcp profile in Adobe DNG Profile Editor and try? Thanks

Comment: @MicroMachine, Did you stop PS, copy file and then run PS?

Comment: Ok, it finally worked. To make it work under current macOS, I had to place it in [UserName]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Camera Raw/Settings/Adobe/Profiles/ and also look under "Browse Profiles" (the squares next to "Profile" then "Profiles" the first time. Didn't seem to work when putting it in the "Settings" folder. Thanks for pointing in the right direction!